# SQL Server stored procedure with Date variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I need help correcting the below stored procedure. I would like to only have to enter the dates as `07-14-2014` and not have to enter the whole `datetime` string and still get all of the data from `07-14-2014`.

Currently I have to enter it as `2014-07-14 00:00:00.000`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spWWGetScrap]
    @Start_Date datetime = NULL
    ,@End_Date datetime = NULL
AS
  -- Get the latest dataset.
  SELECT        
      Casting_Part_Number, Scrap_Code, 
      Casting_Code, Pattern, Quantity
  FROM            
      CleaningRoom_Scrap
  WHERE        
      DateStamp BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
```

Comment: hello...  don't forget to also include a tag with a version (year) for SQL Server.

Comment: also, why do you "have to" enter the time?  How have you seen a problem omitting it?  I ask because normally it will default to 00:00:00 if it is omitted... so you would get what you want.  (I'm guessing you have a problem with "between", and it would be good to get specific about that)

Comment: Also, if you don't need the time component then why not just use `date` type for @Start_Date and @End_Date.

Comment: I need the time for some reports, but not for all.  When I leave the time off and say I just want today (07-14-2014) it doesn't return anything.  if I put the fill times of (07-14-2014 00:00:00.000 and 07-14-2014 23:59:59.000) it will return today's data.

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to learn the answer to the question "[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)".

Comment: I did have it set to  WHERE        (DateStamp >= @Start_Date) AND (DateStamp <= @End_Date)  but that gave the same results.

Comment: @idnarbjm you need to add one day to `end_date`. Do you need help with this? do you understand why?

Comment: That pair of predicates in your comment is an *exact* equivalent of BETWEEN. It is the pattern in @Horaciux's answer that the linked article recommends using instead of BETWEEN (and I happen to agree with that recommendation perfectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include all events in a date period you need to start in 00:00:00.000 start date and finish before next day 00:00:00.000 end date. This can be done easily adding 1 day to end date.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spWWGetScrap]
    @Start_Date datetime = NULL
    ,@End_Date datetime = NULL
AS
  -- Get the latest dataset.
  SELECT        
      Casting_Part_Number, Scrap_Code, 
      Casting_Code, Pattern, Quantity
  FROM            
      CleaningRoom_Scrap
  WHERE        
       (DateStamp >= @Start_Date) AND (DateStamp < dateadd(d,1,@End_Date))
```

Notice I'm not including `=` . This only works when you omit time part in end date.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you all very much for the assistance today.